# pip install TFX taking way too long

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow, tfx

I am trying to deploy a Kubeflow pipeline using TFX. I have upgraded my pip to the latest version but however, the TFX is taking way too longer to get installed. I've installed TFX on my other projects in GCP, but it has never taken this long. Also, I often get this message

`"INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyrsistent to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while."`

Please let me know if this is normal. If it is not, please help me fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pinning a version of pyrsistent?

Comment: No I didn't do that. How do I do that?

Comment: This seems to be a pip related issue in similar context with issue :- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8713
For time being(till a fix is available), please downgrade the pip version and recheck once.

Comment: I downgraded the pip version to 21.2.2 from 21.2.4 and I am still facing the same issue. I let the code over the night but the dependency resolver has just been backtracking on and on

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm also got this problem as well. To solve it, I made list of the requirements.txt for TFX version 1.10, 1.13 and the latest version 1.14.0. Which I'm tested all of these using Anaconda in both Intel and AMD machine. You can check it at

https://www.yodiw.com/solve-tfx-pip-installation-too-long-and-slow/

Or just straight to the requirement file at here https://github.com/yodiaditya/datascience/tree/main/tfx

Hope this can help you to install TFX in your machine!